# How do I throw an Exception from a Spring WebClient POST call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following code that takes sends some data into a PDF generation service which in turn returns the generated PDF as a byte array:

```
try{
        
        //...setup code etc.
        
            byte[] clientResponse = webClient.post()
                    .uri(pdfServiceUrl + pdfMergeAndFillUri)
                    .header("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .body(Mono.just(reqBody), String.class)
                    .retrieve()
                    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> {
                        return Mono.error(new CustomException(response.toString(), "Client Error", response.statusCode().toString()));
                    })
                    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, response -> {
                        return Mono.error(new CustomException(response.toString(), "Server Error", response.statusCode().toString()));
                    })
                    .bodyToMono(byte[].class)
                    .block();
                    
                    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Could not create PDF using document template. " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

I'm not sure what to do with the `Mono.error` that is returned. What I'd like to do is have behavior similar to a `throw`, where I would throw the `CustomException` in the event of an Http error, and process accordingly. How would I do that in this situation?

I'm trying to avoid going back to `RestTemplate` given that it is deprecated.